# Start new cmd.exe from current command line in administrator mode

Tags: windows, command-line, administrator

When I'm currently in a command line window and I change an environmental variable I have to reopen a cmd.exe instance. When I want to install a python package using pip from the command line I have to run it in administrator mode as well.

I was wondering if there is a command / shortcut to reopen a cmd.exe instance in administrator mode.

I know I can use `start cmd.exe` to open a new command line instance and I've seen that apparently you can use `runas` to run a service from the command line in administrator mode, but this prompted me for my administrator password which does not correspond to my user password apparently.

Comment: If the user you are logged into, is not an Administrator, you will have to input an elevated user's permissions in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you already started `cmd` as administrator then you can simply create another (child) copy of administrative console that will inherit parent's environment without providing admin's password by simply running:

```
start
```

so in your case set environment variables you need in parent administrative console, then run `start`